# perft-function of chess engine is giving self-contradictory output

Tags: c++, recursion, c++17, chess

I am currently developing a chess engine in C++, and I am in the process of debugging my move generator. For this purpose, I wrote a simple `perft()` function:

```
int32_t Engine::perft(GameState game_state, int32_t depth)
{
    int32_t last_move_nodes = 0;
    int32_t all_nodes = 0;

    Timer timer;
    timer.start();

    int32_t output_depth = depth;

    if (depth == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<Move> legal_moves = generator.generate_legal_moves(game_state);

    for (Move move : legal_moves)
    {
        game_state.make_move(move);

        last_move_nodes = perft_no_print(game_state, depth - 1);
        all_nodes += last_move_nodes;

        std::cout << index_to_square_name(move.get_from_index()) << index_to_square_name(move.get_to_index()) << ": " << last_move_nodes << "\n";

        game_state.unmake_move(move);
    }

    std::cout << "\nDepth: " << output_depth << "\nTotal nodes: " << all_nodes << "\nTotal time: " << timer.get_milliseconds() << "ms/" << timer.get_milliseconds()/1000.0f << "s\n\n";

    return all_nodes;
}

int32_t Engine::perft_no_print(GameState game_state, int32_t depth)
{
    int32_t nodes = 0;

    if (depth == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<Move> legal_moves = generator.generate_legal_moves(game_state);

    for (Move move : legal_moves)
    {
        game_state.make_move(move);

        nodes += perft_no_print(game_state, depth - 1);

        game_state.unmake_move(move);
    }

    return nodes;
}
```

It's results for the initial chess position (FEN: `rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1`) for depths `1` and `2` match the results of stockfish's `perft` command, so I assume they are correct:

```
h2h3: 1
h2h4: 1
g2g3: 1
g2g4: 1
f2f3: 1
f2f4: 1
e2e3: 1
e2e4: 1
d2d3: 1
d2d4: 1
c2c3: 1
c2c4: 1
b2b3: 1
b2b4: 1
a2a3: 1
a2a4: 1
g1h3: 1
g1f3: 1
b1c3: 1
b1a3: 1

Depth: 1
Total nodes: 20
Total time: 1ms/0.001s

h2h3: 20
h2h4: 20
g2g3: 20
g2g4: 20
f2f3: 20
f2f4: 20
e2e3: 20
e2e4: 20
d2d3: 20
d2d4: 20
c2c3: 20
c2c4: 20
b2b3: 20
b2b4: 20
a2a3: 20
a2a4: 20
g1h3: 20
g1f3: 20
b1c3: 20
b1a3: 20

Depth: 2
Total nodes: 400
Total time: 1ms/0.001s
```

The results stop matching at depth 3, though:

*Stockfish:*

```
go perft 3
a2a3: 380
b2b3: 420
c2c3: 420
d2d3: 539
e2e3: 599
f2f3: 380
g2g3: 420
h2h3: 380
a2a4: 420
b2b4: 421
c2c4: 441
d2d4: 560
e2e4: 600
f2f4: 401
g2g4: 421
h2h4: 420
b1a3: 400
b1c3: 440
g1f3: 440
g1h3: 400

Nodes searched: 8902
```

*My engine:*

```
h2h3: 361
h2h4: 380
g2g3: 340
g2g4: 397
f2f3: 360
f2f4: 436
e2e3: 380
e2e4: 437
d2d3: 380
d2d4: 437
c2c3: 399
c2c4: 326
b2b3: 300
b2b4: 320
a2a3: 280
a2a4: 299
g1h3: 281
g1f3: 280
b1c3: 357
b1a3: 320

Depth: 3
Total nodes: 7070
Total time: 10ms/0.01s
```

I figured that my move generator was just buggy, and tried to track down the bugs by making a move the engine gives incorrect values for on the board and then calling `perft()` with `depth = 2` on it to find out which moves are missing. But for all moves I tried this with, the engine suddenly starts to output the correct results I expected to get earlier!

Here is an example for the move `a2a3`:

1. When calling `perft()` on the initial position in **stockfish**, it calculates `380` subnodes for `a2a3` at depth `3`.
2. When calling `perft()` on the initial position in **my engine**, it calculates `280` subnodes for `a2a3` at depth `3`.
3. When calling `perft()` on the position you get after making the move `a2a3` in the initial position in **my engine**, it calculates the correct number of total nodes at depth `2`, `380`:

```
h7h5: 19
h7h6: 19
g7g5: 19
g7g6: 19
f7f5: 19
f7f6: 19
e7e5: 19
e7e6: 19
d7d5: 19
d7d6: 19
c7c5: 19
c7c6: 19
b7b5: 19
b7b6: 19
a7a5: 19
a7a6: 19
g8h6: 19
g8f6: 19
b8c6: 19
b8a6: 19

Depth: 2
Total nodes: 380
Total time: 1ms/0.001s
```

If you have any idea what the problem could be here, please help me out. Thank you!

**EDIT**:

I discovered some interesting new facts that might help to solve the problem, but I don't know what to do with them:

1. For some reason, using `std::sort()` like this in `perft()`:

   ```
   std::sort(legal_moves.begin(), legal_moves.end(), [](auto first, auto second){     return first.get_from_index() % 8 > second.get_from_index() % 8; });
   ```

   to sort the vector of legal moves causes the found number of total nodes for the initial position (for depth `3`) to change from the wrong `7070` to the (also wrong) `7331`.
2. When printing the game state after calling `game_state.make_move()` in `perft()`, it seems to have had no effect on the position bitboards (the other properties change like they are supposed to). This is very strange, because isolated, the `make_move()` method works just fine.

Comment: hard for us to help debug such a complex codebase without seeing it. My main suggestion, dont assume you know where the fault lies, do the long haul single step debug method. (You said it cant be the move generator, why not). Make sure you dont have any UB, use valgrind if you can, turn up compiler warnings to max

Comment: Without all of the code, it is not more than a guess, but maybe `make_move` is buggy or `unmake_move` does not really unmake everything

Comment: @pm100 What I meant was that, while still possibly not being 100% correct all the time, in this example, the move generator can not really be the cause of the problem I am describing. That is because of what I am explaining in the example I made above: The move generator is able to generate the correct moves for position B with depth 2, but not for position A with depth 3, although is should be able to do that, because position B is a position that can directly be achieved by making a move in position A.

Comment: Given that you have problems with the starting position for depth I would assume you have something wrong in your make or unmake move code that has to do with captures, that is whree I would start looking. Generally in perft you want to see what sort of "special" moves that can be made at the depth you are at and focus on those cases. Most of the times the quiet moves works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure if you were able to pin down the issue but from the limited information available in the question, the best I can assume (and something I faced myself earlier) is that there is a problem in your `unmake_move()` function when it comes to captures since

1. Your perft fails only at level 3 - this is when the first legal capture is possible, move 1 and 2 can have no legal captures.
2. Your perft works fine when it's at depth 1 in the position after `a2a3` rather than when it's searching at depth 3 from the start

This probably means that your `unmake_move()` fails at a depth greater than 1 where you need to restore some of the board's state that cannot be derived from just the `move` parameter you are passing in (e.g. enpassant, castling rights etc. before you made the move).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you and also thought the problem couldn't be the movegen, however it was. Somewhere in the code when adding a capture move to the movelist, you are not inputting the captured piece.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you would like to debug your move generator using perft.

1. Given startpos as p1, generate perft(3) for your engine and sf. (you did that)
2. Now check any move that have different nodes, you pick a2a3. (you did that)
3. Given startpos + a2a3 as p2, generate perft(2) for **your engine** and **sf**. (you partially did this)
4. Now check any move that have different nodes in step 3. Let's say move x.
5. Given startpos + a2a3 + x as p3, generate perft(1) for **your engine** and **sf**.

Since that is only perft(1) by this time you will be able to figure out the wrong move or the missing move from your generator. Setup that last position or p3 on the board and see the wrong/missing moves from your engine compared to sf perft(1) result.